# Is there a way to pass a functions reference but also give it a parameter?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generalize a single function for handling different events in JavaScript. Meaning that depending on the event listener that was called my function needs to behave in a different way. However, I can only pass the reference to my function, which is where my problem arises.

In order for my function to behave properly I need to know which event handler called it. But if I can only pass by reference, I can't pass a parameter which tells me who the function caller was. So is there a way to pass a functions reference but also allow it to accept a parameter?

Here is some general code that hopefully illustrates my question.

```
btn1.AddEventListener("Click", myFunction);
btn2.AddEventListener("Click", myFunction);

function myFunction(caller){
   if(caller == someObject)
   {
    //do something
   }
   else
   {
    //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: By `someObject`, do you mean `btn1` or `btn2`, for example?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the function, you can either examine the `this`, which will refer to the element the listener was added to, or the first parameter (the `event`)'s `currentTarget`, which will refer to the same thing:

```
function myFunction(event) {
  if (event.currentTarget === btn1) {
    // btn1 was clicked
  } else {
    // btn2 was clicked
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) is useful for this kind of event handlers. To create a closure wrap the function call with another anonymous function like:

```
btn1.AddEventListener("Click", () => myFunction(btn1));
btn2.AddEventListener("Click", () => myFunction(btn2));
```

Also, you can pass additional arguments as much as you want like:

```
btn1.AddEventListener("Click", () => myFunction(btn1, another_param));

function myFunction(btn, param){
    // ... do something with param.
}
```

With the traditional notation, this is equivalent to following:

```
btn1.AddEventListener("Click", function () {
                         return myFunction(btn1);
                      });
```